# Executing requests double quote

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, psycopg2

I tried to enter values in a database automatically.

for each table, I list the number of columns that are contained in an xml file, then I'm going to fetch the data in a pandas dataframe

```
            column = ""
            values = []
            for i, tables in enumerate(bddXml):
                for test in range(len(tables[1])):
                    column += (tables[1][test][0])
                    values.append(tables[1][test][1])


                table = Identifier(str(tables[0]))
                column = Identifier(str(column))
                value = Identifier(str(a[values].to_string(index=False, header=False)).strip())


                cur.execute(SQL("""INSERT INTO {table}({column}) VALUES({value});""").format(table=table,column=column, value=value))

                column = []
                values = []
```

when I test my code, it returns this error to me

```
INSERT INTO "users"("login") VALUES("...")
```

the problem is due to the ", there should normally be single quote

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I showed what I was entering in data,  {table} = users    {column} = "login"   {value} = "text"

Comment: You have provided any examples of your input data (i.e. table = ?, Column = ?, value = ?), also you haven't shown your error message.  Given, the information you have provided, I don't believe it is possible to answer your question.

Comment: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "nom
  nom
nom
  " does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "users"("login") VALUES("rstaub

Comment: the data are huge I can't write them here, but the error is indicated in the code snippet as well as the entries, I don't see what else I can mark...

Comment: I wouldn't expect you ton provide all the data, but a sample of the data that illustrates the error condition.   See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.